# Integration on manifold

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, calculus

How can we generalised those integration by parts to arbitrary manifold?
$$\int_{+\infty} ^{-\infty} f(x). g(x) \,dx$$
$$=
f(x)\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} g(x)-\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} [f'(x)\int g(x)dx]\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

You use Stokes' theorem:
$$
\int_\Omega d\omega= \int_{\partial \Omega} \omega
$$
If you are not familiar with differential forms, you can also use the usual form of the divergence theorem
$$
\int_M \nabla_\mu J^\mu \sqrt{g}d^nx = \int_{\partial M} J^\mu dS_\mu,
$$
together with the fact that $\nabla_\mu$ is a derivation.